# How to redirect Thank you cloud page to URL based on response

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture

What I'm looking to achieve:

1. (done)User selects item from list of items either
   a)within email form OR
   b)from fallback cloudpage smart capture form.
2. (done)user then gets directed to thank you cloud page.
3. (lost on how to approach this) based on response on the single question, the thank you cloud page then further directs to a next external link based on response in step 1.

In my Thank you Page I have:

```
%%[ 
IF RequestParameter("ItemSelected") == 'Item1' THEN   
   SET @URL = 'https://www.customURL.com' 
ELSE   
   SET @URL = 'https://www.default.com' 
ENDIF 
]%%
 
meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=%%=v(@URL)=%%"
```

But is it possible to have the ItemSelected value sent in the URL parameter to the cloud page and then that value picked up in the thank you page to be applied?

I know this sounds very amateur but my head is spinning and can't find a working solution.

Comment: If I get ur requirement right, by using `<input type="hidden" name="ItemSelected">` you can pass values from once page to another... also you can use `Redirect()` function in your thank you page to redirect... you can `Concat(@URL,RequestParameter('ItemSelected')` to send value to external link

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUUUUUU